# Communicate between two (or n) scripts - events

Tags: javascript, events, module, pixi.js

I'm working on a small game made with PIXI.JS for the canvas rendering and with ReactJS for the all interface. The game is half interface half game so it's pretty big, that's why I used a framework for it.

**Problem**

I decompose my game in two scripts : the "core" for the Management of the game, a bit like a controller and I have a second repository for the interface.

I want to communicate between the interface and the core, but I'm stuck because i have no idea, how I should do it. Do you have any idea

Small schema to represent my idea : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAHRi.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app"></div>

        <script src="./core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./ui.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Ideas**

- Global variable of core.min.js so I can access the main Class.
- Event system (But still stuck on how to have the same on both)

Thanks.

--- Added:

Folder structure :

```
├─ .gitignore
├─ lerna-debug.log
├─ lerna.json
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
└─ packages
   ├─ core
   │  ├─ package-lock.json
   │  ├─ package.json
   |  |─ source
   │  |  └─ index.js
   │  ├─ README.md
   │  └─ webpack.config.babel.js
   ├─ interface
   │  ├─ package-lock.json
   │  ├─ package.json
   │  ├─ README.md
   │  |─ webpack.config.babel.js
   |  └─ source
   |     ├─ index.html
   |     ├─ index.js
   |     └─ index.scss
```

So you have 1 webpack configuration for each sub packages : 1 for core, and one for the interface. Like I told in the comment, we could create multiple interface that could work with the core.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Could you clarify the end goal for us to better help?

Comment: yes - i agree with @JohnPavek above - please explain what you are trying to achieve instead of describing attempted solution. My question is: why you splitted your code into 2 compiled/minified js files? Why it cant be in 1 file? 1 compiled file doesnt mean that your original source code cant consist of many small files (one per class etc)

Comment: We would like to split the core and the interface so we could totally modified the interface. Like a lego brick that can be replace by another interface totally different but still have the same core. @domis86. [ Modified on client side ] , Maybe i shoud look into loadjs/scriptjs but I don't find any thing interesting with UMD / AMD..

Comment: @ThomasDELAPORTE I would say that you should do the "splitting" or "separation of components" at code level before you will want to do it at repository level. You can have several components in you application - and if you design them well then they will be replecable. Dont confuse it with having 2 compiled files. But anyway: i dont see any source code so i cant give you more specific advice. Can you edit your question and show at least folder structure with js files (the not compiled ones) ?

Comment: @domis86 I added the folder structure , maybe that could help. The thing is that we want to make this project modular, the core is independant from the interface. So other user can create other interface (with other framework for example) and just communicate with the core.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so generally first thing you want to check when you want to have "independent" components is: coupling. You need to ensure that those components does not depend on each other: does not have "tight coupling" (one component calls some "internal" method from other component, or accesses variable from other component, or global variable/function etc).

Then you need to define some kind of "contract" between those components - so some kind of API and/or events. You need to think about:

- which kind of public methods should be exposed by one component so they can be called by second component - and vice versa: maybe the second component need sometimes call some exposed method from first component.
- which kind of public events should be dispatched by one compoenent so they can be handled by second component. Example: lets say that our game has a score counter which is displayed in the UI ("interface" from your description) - but the score itself is being kept in "core" component (so "core" is a "source of truth" for informations about "score"). We can define event "GAME_SCORE_CHANGED" which contains information about new score. Such event will be dispatched by one component - "core" - and handled by second component "interface". The "interface" in such case will update displayed score.

Such contract, once defined, need to be respected by both components. If you anticipate that contract may need to be changed in future (in sense of API, events etc) then you will also need to plan a versioning system. Then one component will be allowed to upgrade itself to newer version independently of other components. After some time other components may adapt such newer version. However there is a disadvantage: backward compatibility with older versions - in other words: you need to support all previous versions if you know that other components are still using them.

To ensure this contract is still being respected you can implement various automatic tests (btw: not only for this - you should use automatic testing for everything wherever possible ;) it will pay off in long run) - for example:

- test behaviour of one component when other component is mocked
- integration tests
- end2end tests (using Selenium, PhantomJS, headless Chrome etc).

All of those things mentioned above are of course not easy :) Thats why usually for small applications people doesnt do such approach - because it requires certain amount of overhead, planning and discipline.

Now, as from the project structure that you shown i see some problem: the `index.html` file is inside `interface` component. This means that `interface` component will need to initialize `core` component - because you need to start the application in some place inside html document. This is already some kind of coupling :) It could be solved probably by introducing another component: a small one that will "orchestrate" those 2 components.

Also, especially in the early phase of the project development i would advise to keep those components in one repository. Later when you will be familiar with this architecture, and components will grow larger and mature, then you can think about splitting them to separate repos.

Please read more details about what i said in following links:

- https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract